# Ruby on Rails undefined method `discussions_path' - nested resource, one-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

The problem seems so simple, but I just can't seem to fix it. I must be missing something obvious, but would really appreciate any help at all!

Error message that appears:

```
undefined method `discussions_path' for #<#<Class:0x000001032e90d8>:0x000001030f1168>
```

Routes file:

```
resources :forums do
  resources :discussions
end
```

Discussions/_form.html.erb file:

```
<%= form_for [@forum, @discussion] do |f| %>  
 <%= f.error_messages %>
 <p>  
  <%= f.label :name %><br />  
  <%= f.text_field :name %>  
 </p>
 <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>  
<% end %>
```

Discussions controller new action:

```
def new
  @forum = Forum.find_by_permalink(params[:id])
  @discussion = Discussion.new
end
```

This is full error I'm now getting (in Terminal):

```
Started GET "/forums/general-chat/discussions/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-14 18:35:28 +0100
Processing by DiscussionsController#new as HTML
Parameters: {"forum_id"=>"general-chat"}
Forum Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "forums".* FROM "forums" WHERE "forums"."permalink" IS NULL LIMIT 1
Rendered layouts/_content_full_start.html.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered discussions/_form.html.erb (574.4ms)
Rendered discussions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (575.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 581ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For nested resources you need to pass an array in to `form_for` with the forum and discussion, e.g. set `@forum` in your controller, and then in the view use:

```
<%= form_for [@forum, @discussion] do |f| %>
```

From the [rails docs](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4f66586bbfacbce4c07f2b9d8d142be1bf6d4e5e/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L239):

```
If your resource has associations defined, for example, you want to add comments
to the document given that the routes are set correctly:
<%= form_for([@document, @comment]) do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
Where @document = Document.find(params[:id]) and @comment = Comment.new.
```

Comment: Hmm, I did think passing both would be the case, but I seem to be getting the same error: undefined method discussions_path. My _form.html.erb now begins with this: `<%= form_for [@forum, @discussion] do |f| %>` and my discussions controller new action is now: `def new
    @discussion = Discussion.new
    @forum = Forum.find_by_permalink(params[:id])
  end` - just to note, I am using permalinks instead of ids in the urls.

Comment: I don't think so - but I've updated my original question with the suggested code added - and the full error (from Terminal) that is displayed when I try to load /forums/general-chat/discussions/new

Comment: The query in your log is: `SELECT "forums".* FROM "forums" WHERE "forums"."permalink" IS NULL LIMIT 1`, so unless you have a forum with a NULL permalink `@forum` will be getting set to `nil` (which will cause `form_for` to fail). I think you want: `@forum = Forum.find_by_permalink(params[:forum_id])`

Comment: Perfect! That makes perfect sense, thanks a lot for your help!